# Question regarding induction

Tags: solution-verification, induction

Hi I'm trying to prove Tribonacci number ($f_n= f_{n-1} + f_{n-2} + f_{n-3}$ for $n \geq 4$): $f_n > 3n$ for all $n > 9$ by strong induction. I know this seems a very easy proof but I'm facing a problem of choosing base case and induction hypothesis here.

I tried base case to be n=10 which is true because $f_{10} = 44 > 30$. And using $f_k > 3k$ as induction hypothesis. then when at $k+1$: we need to show that $f_{k+1} = f_k + f_{k-1} + f_{k-2}$ is greater than $3k+3$. Since $f_k > 3k \implies f_{k+1} > 3k + f_{k-1} + f_{k-2}$

by strong induction can I just say that $f_{k-1} > 3(k-1)$? but this is not true for $k = 9$ since the base case is $10$. Or my approach is incorrect?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is slightly incorrect. Strong induction requires first proving the base case (in this case $n_0 = 10$), then assuming that the statement $P(n)$ is true for all $10\leq n \leq k$, and then proving it for $k+1$. Therefore, the proof you provide is correct if $k\geq 12$, but the cases $k=10$ and $k=11$ must be individually (separately) checked. I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi! thank you for answering! Do you mean if I also check for case k =10 and case k=11, then the approach is correct?

Comment: Yes! The only thing that you would have to do is check the property for $f_{11}$ and $f_{12}$

Comment: thank you for your help!!